# python - how to append to a dictionary where the dictionary name is a variable

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that I am iterating through. Each of the dictionaries  has the same set of keys. I want to be able to append each item in the list to a new set of 7 dictionaries where the 7 dictionaries are each elements of a specific key.

For example if the dictionaries in the list has a key called 'houses' with values 'Dis' 'Brobnar', I want to have dictionares called 'Dis' and 'Brobnar' that will contain the entire dictionary.

Here's what I've tried, but it fails with an error message -

```
cards = [
{'house':'Dis','card_title':'Bob'},
{'house':'Brobnar','card_title':'Fred'},
]

Dis = {}
for i in cards:
    if i['house'] == 'Dis':
        i['house'].append(i)
```

error

```
i['house'].append(i)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

wanted results

```
Dis = [
{'house':'Dis','card_title':'Bob'},
]
Brobnar = [
{'house':'Brobnar','card_title':'Fred'},
]
```

Comment: Dynamically creating variables is almost always a bad idea. I suggest you to wrap everything inside another dictionary, such that the house names become keys.

Comment: `i['house'].` gives you a string key, you can't append to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with [@Selcuk's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661461/python-how-to-append-to-a-dictionary-where-the-dictionary-name-is-a-variable#comment94181282_53661461), so i am going to do an dictionary instead:

```
d={}.fromkeys([i['house'] for i in cards],[])
d={k:[i for i in cards if i['house']==k] for k,v in d.items()}
```

And now:

```
print(d)
```

Is:

```
{'Dis': [{'house': 'Dis', 'card_title': 'Bob'}], 'Brobnar': [{'house': 'Brobnar', 'card_title': 'Fred'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already allocated your variable and just want to append to them, you need to create a wrapper dictionary to point to them:

```
cards = [
{'house':'Dis','card_title':'Bob'},
{'house':'Brobnar','card_title':'Fred'},
]

Dis = []
Brobnar = []

wrapper = {
    'Dis':Dis,
    'Brobnar':Brobnar,
}

for i in cards:
    if not wrapper.get(i['house'], None) is None:
        wrapper[i['house']].append(i)

print( Dis)
print( Brobnar)

#[{'house': 'Dis', 'card_title': 'Bob'}]
#[{'house': 'Brobnar', 'card_title': 'Fred'}]
```